# Open Source Document Management System in .net?

Tags: .net, open-source

Are there any open source Document Management Systems built on .NET ? We've found a plenty of Java-based open source DMS but none on .NET.

Also, please note that we do not look for (Web)Content Management solutions but Document Management.

Thank you,
Catalin

Comment: Can you clarify the features you're looking for in a DMS?

Comment: @Out "DMS" refers to a standard set of functionalities; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_management_system#Overview

Comment: Well, consider SharePoint, which offers DMS but may be more (or even less) than what the OP is looking for.

Comment: SharePoint is not open source... and SharePoint isn't a very good solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is, do you really need open source?  Or just no cost?

If the latter, then Windows Sharepoint Services (WSS) is a pretty good DMS.  It's free from Microsoft, and you can write .NET code to enhance it if you want.  It doesn't have all the Office Sharepoint stuff, but it's pretty good.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend you to check out [Sense/Net](http://sensenet.com/) - it's free and open source.

It's one of the few open source software that supports document management with the office protocol. So you can just click on a link on a site and it will automaticall open your files with Microsoft Office. It also supports versioning and many other features.

You can have a look at their source code and releases here:
http://sensenet.codeplex.com/

Comment: Latest link to Sensenet code: https://github.com/SenseNet/

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/doclib/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/clic-dms/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dotdms/

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a standalone app that offers a huge range of features I'd stand by Perceptive Software's ImageNow.  It's not exactly built on .NET, because it's all Visual C++.  It has both desktop and web based document management solutions.  [ImageNow](http://www.imagenow.com)