# What NoSQL solutions are out there for a .NET develop for a DMS

Tags: .net, nosql, dms

We should start the develop of an application...DMS - Doocument Management System.

Which is the best solution for a NoSql database (document database?) ?

We are develop in .net --> so c#, linq and silverlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would NoSQL be the best solution for a DMS? Or will you use it in conjunction with a SQL base?

See this SO question for possible NoSQL solutions in .Net.
[What NoSQL solutions are out there for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777103/what-nosql-solutions-are-out-there-for-net)

My favorite is RavenDB as it's all .Net.

Comment: I need non-structured stored information with fast retrieval...I'm thinking a "structured" Lucene solution...what do you think?

Comment: I'm all for Lucene and NoSQL ;) But your needed capabilities tells you what's the best solution. Things to think about: User database, document meta data, search, security, query flexibility. Fast retrieval can be achived with a SQL base as well, depending on your needs and architecture. And you can always add caching layers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post like yours (it's not about no SQL):
[Open Source Document Management System in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829888/open-source-document-management-system-in-net)

I believe Sharepoint is the best DMS for windows-based corporations. What is obvious is a DMS need to save documents meta-data some where and the performance of a DMS is dependent of the speed of accessing meta-data how ever if you need an small DMS you can change the DAL (data access layer) of a famous one to use something like a flat XML engine as data-store. There are many on Codeplex.

You can find open source .NET applications at : http://www.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of NOSql dbs, for example look at [couch db](http://couchdb.apache.org/), [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/), or if you want something puerly net based [ravendb](http://ravendb.net/).  All of them are useable from .NET.

However if you are going to develop a document management system, it might be a good idea to look at already existing solutions for example sharepoint of alfresco.